# Does ftplib pass username/password in plain text?

Tags: python, ftplib

I am deploying a system to a remote location that will have internet access and I would like to transfer the data to an ftp site.  I have typically done this using Python's ftplib, but due to the length of the deployment I am more concerned on security.  I could implement Paramiko (actually, I likely will since it can "ssh"), but I wonder how ftplib handles the username/password exchange with the server.  Are these parameters passed in plain text, or is plain-text only used when transferring data?  I see nothing in the documentation to indicate one way or the other.

Comment: Look at Fabric from deployment via SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, FTP was not designed to be a secure protocol, and *does* send in plaintext (even login credentials).  It could easily be sniffed and read.

for security, have a look at some alternatives:

- SSH
- SCP
- SFTP
- FTPS

for Python, [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) (SSH) is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Corey.  I was afraid FTP did something so ridiculous as plaintext login.  I have used Paramiko before, and will likely use it for the current project.  Thanks again.